# Creating a custom Table Style for PowerPoint table

Tags: xml, powerpoint, tabular

I am creating a custom table style for a powerpoint table. Where I am having issues is formatting the first column. There are two items I want to implement.

1. I want the text in the first column = blue
2. I want the right border of the first column to be blue

The below is a copy of my `tablestyles.xml` code. Specifically where I need help is understanding why `<a:firstCo>` is not working as coded (yes, I am new to this).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<a:tblStyleLst xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" def="{5C22544A-7EE6-4342-B048-85BDC9FD1C3A}">

    <a:tblStyle styleId="{13FEF9DA-6794-4BE8-A12E-2D652123F822}" styleName="CMB Custom Table">
        <a:wholeTbl>
            <a:tcStyle> 
                <a:tcBdr>
                    <a:left> <a:lnRef idx="0"><a:scrgbClr r="0" g="0" b="0"/> </a:lnRef></a:left>
                    <a:right> <a:lnRef idx="0"><a:scrgbClr r="0" g="0" b="0"/> </a:lnRef></a:right>
                    <a:bottom> <a:lnRef idx="3"><a:schemeClr val="accent1"/> </a:lnRef></a:bottom>
                    <a:insideH> <a:lnRef idx="1"><a:schemeClr val="accent2"/> </a:lnRef></a:insideH>
                    <a:insideV> <a:lnRef idx="1"><a:schemeClr val="accent2"/> </a:lnRef></a:insideV>
                </a:tcBdr>
            </a:tcStyle>
        </a:wholeTbl>


        <a:firstCol>
            <a:tcTxStyle>
                <a:fontRef idx="minor"/>
                <a:schemeClr val="accent3"/>
            </a:tcTxStyle>
            <a:tcStyle>                 
                <a:tcBdr>
                    <a:right> <a:lnRef idx="3"><a:schemeClr val="accent3"/> </a:lnRef > </a:right>
                </a:tcBdr>
            </a:tcStyle>

        </a:firstCol>

        <a:firstRow>
            <a:tcTxStyle>
                <a:fontRef idx="minor"/>
                <a:schemeClr val="accent1"/>
            </a:tcTxStyle>
            <a:tcStyle>
                <a:tcBdr>
                    <a:top><a:lnRef idx="0"><a:scrgbClr r="0" g="0" b="0"/></a:lnRef></a:top>
                    <a:bottom><a:lnRef idx="3"><a:schemeClr val="accent1"/></a:lnRef></a:bottom>
                </a:tcBdr>              
            </a:tcStyle>                
        </a:firstRow>       
    </a:tblStyle>

</a:tblStyleLst>
```

Comment: @Senshin do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Nope. I don't know jack about powerpoint.